# Insert just the code of jupyter notebook to latex

Tags: python, latex

I am trying to insert a brief python notebook, less than half a page, into my latex thesis. I am using

```
\includepdf[
%% Include all pages of the PDF
pages=-,
%% make this page have the usual page style
%% (you can change it to plain etc). By default pdfpages
%% sets the pagecommand to \pagestyle{empty}
pagecommand={\pagestyle{headings}},  
%% Add a "section" entry to the ToC with the heading
%% "Quilling Shapes" and the label "sec:shapes"
addtotoc={1,section,1,Quilling Shapes,sec:shapes}]
%% The pdf file itself
{document.pdf}
```

But the problem is that the entire pdf with the code is inserted to the original latex file, so it looks like there is a lot of white space at the end of the code of the jupyter notebook in the original latex. Does anyone know an option to get just the adjusted notebook into the latex and not the white space down below of the pdf ?

Comment: `\includepdf` is for full pages. If you just want to embed a smaller pdf on a page, use `\includegraphic` You can use `trim` to clip away any white space you don't like.

Comment: Thanks, it works fine that approach!